# AngularJS - Scope doesn't updates inside jquery ui dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, angularjs-scope

For example,

1. I have two templates `route_one` and `route_two`.
2. In `route_one`, I have a link which open a jquery ui dialog. Inside the dialog, I can
       push some values to a scope where the list of added values will be
       displayed using `ng-repeat`.

Here is the **problem**, I have added some values to the scope, then I go to `route_two` and again come back to the `route one`. At this point the scope should be empty, but it still holds the older values.

I have created a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/xVtiYBwoM6h8SJpBIUh9?p=preview) for you reference.

http://plnkr.co/edit/xVtiYBwoM6h8SJpBIUh9?p=preview

Steps to replicate the issue,

1. click `show dialog`
2. Add some values. You will see, the values will be displayed in both main page and inside the dialog.
3. click `Goto Rotue Two`
4. click `Back`
5. Since the scope is empty, the values displayed in the main page will be cleared. But the problem is, it is not updated inside the
   dialog.

I have tried `$apply` and `$compile`, doesn't works as expected.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your `back()`-method which uses `window.history.back();`.

Replace

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" ng-click="back();">Back</a>
```

with

```
<a href="#!/route_one">Goto Route One</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Phylax pointed it absolutely correct. You may use  tag and give href or you may also use

$location.path('/route_one') , if you want to use angular routing

Answer (score 0):

Got it! It is simple, I have to destroy the dialog once it is closed.

Have a look at the updated [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/Y8yVyp11h8FmKXQxcKXx?p=preview)

http://plnkr.co/edit/Y8yVyp11h8FmKXQxcKXx?p=preview

var route_one = angular.module('routeOne', []);

```
route_one.controller('route_one_controller', ['$scope', 
  function($scope){
    $scope.values = [];

    $scope.add_values = function(){
      if($scope.new_value.length <= 0){ return false; }
      $scope.values.push({name: $scope.new_value});
      $scope.new_value = '';
      $('#dialog').dialog('close');
    };

    $scope.show_dialog = function(){
      $('#dialog').dialog({
        height: 'auto',
        width: 370,
        resizable: false,
        autoOpen: false,
        close: function(){
          $(this).dialog('destroy');
        }
      });
      $('#dialog').dialog('open');
    };
  }
]);
```